# How to produce different random numbers for only one random number generator and keeping the others same

Tags: c, random, numbers, random-seed

I have a program where I use drand48 and many parts of the program. The program requirement is such that you need the program to generate the same numbers each time, except for one part where i need to have the program generate different numbers in different runs.

Now if I use `srand(time(NULL))` at the beginning of the program (as suggested in many forums), I end up changing all the numbers when I run the program multiple times.

If I use `srand(time(NULL))` inside the relevant loop where I want the change to take place (across program runs), nothing happens and there is no change of random numbers.

Is there a solution to this ???

Answer (score 0):

The C libraries support various different random number generators.

`drand48()` belongs to a family of functions that generate 48-bit pseudorandom values based on the formula *r*<sub>*n*+1</sub> = (*a* · *r*<sub>*n*</sub> + *c*) mod *m*, where *a* = 0xfdeece66d, *c* = 0xb, and *m* = 2<sup>48</sup>. To set a new random seed for these functions, you have to use either `srand48()` or `seed48()`.

`srand()` won't have any effect on these functions because it belongs to a different system of calls that includes `rand()`. But this means you can continue to use `drand48()` in places where you want your random numbers to be repeatable, and `srand()`/`rand()` in places where you want the random numbers to be different each time.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a GNU system, you can use the [`drand48_r()][1]` interface to achieve this.

```
__thread struct drand48_data drand48_same_buffer;
double drand48_same () {
    double x;
    drand48_r(&drand48_same_buffer, &x);
    return x;
}
```

I used the `__thread` GCC extension to create a per-thread instance of the random number state buffer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to tune the **parameters** of the underlying generator, follow jxh's advice; if you're happy with just a different seed, simply use `drand48`'s cousin, `erand48`.

EDIT: are you using the bionic libc? because the discussion at [Undefined reference error - rand](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9926069/undefined-reference-error-rand) revealed that bionic's rand() is just a wrapper around drand48 and friends (bug,bug,bug!)