# Generate random number between 1 and 9 in c++

Tags: c++

What do I need to add, so that it will not continuously choose the number as 8 but rather any of the numbers 1 through 9? srand?

```
int main()
{
   int iRand = (rand() % 9+1);

    if (iRand==1)
    {
        cout << "The planet of the day is Mercury!" <<endl;
        cout << "Mercury is the closest planet to the sun." <<endl;
    }
    else if (iRand==2)
    {
        cout << "The planet of the day is Venus!" <<endl;
        cout << "Venus is the hottest planet in our solar system." <<endl;
    }
    //  .... 3..4..5..6..7..8

    else
    {
        cout << "The planet of the day is Pluto!" <<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Have a look at the `srand()` function.

Comment: If you're compiler supports C++11, it might be wise to ditch `rand()` and use the new random facilities. This question is most likely a duplicate too.

Comment: Looks like you need to watch your parenthesis ().  Try `(rand()%8)+1`.

Comment: Pluto is not a planet anymore... ;)

Comment: Pluto still *wants* to be a planet, and I am glad that you aren't hurting Pluto's feelings.

Comment: well, (rand()%9) would give you values 0..8, and then +1 gives you 1..9

Comment: possible duplicate of [Rand Implementation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768180/rand-implementation)

Answer (score 3):

You need to initialize your [random seed](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_seed) first!

```
#include <stdlib.h>     /* srand, rand */
#include <time.h>       /* time */

srand (time(NULL));
```

Pseudorandom number generators like `rand()` aren't actually totally random. Instead, the numbers are determined by the generator's initial state, called a seed. Your program, as it exists now, will have the same seed on every execution--and thus the random number will be the same every time.

`srand()` to the rescue -- it lets you specify the seed.

If you were to specify a constant seed (like `srand(2)`) then you'd have the same problem as now, just with a different result. Thus, to guarantee differing results every time the program executes, we can initialize the random number generator with the current time -- so as long as you never travel in time, you'll never get the exact same sequence of numbers.

(Note: in a real world applications, this might not be good, because someone could repeat past results by (e.g.) manually resetting the system clock to different times. Which [someone did once](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ronald_Dale_Harris) to steal money from a casino.)