# How does calling srand more than once affect the quality of randomness?

Tags: c++, random, srand

This [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209117/having-issues-with-two-different-objects-within-classtemplate#comment42900202_27209117), which states:

> `srand(time(0));` I would put this line as the first line in main()
>   instead if calling it multiple times (**which will actually lead to less
>   random numbers**).

...and I've bolded the line which I'm having an issue with... repeats common advice to call [`srand`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand) once in a program. Questions like [srand() — why call only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-only-once) re-iterate that because `time(0)` returns the current time in seconds, that multiple calls to `srand` within the same second will produce the same seed. A common workaround is to use milliseconds or nanoseconds instead.

However, I don't understand why this means that `srand` should or can only be called once, or how it leads to **less random** numbers.

[cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/srand):

> Generally speaking, the pseudo-random number generator should only be
>   seeded once, before any calls to rand(), and the start of the program.
>   **It should not be repeatedly seeded, or reseeded every time you wish to generate a new batch of pseudo-random numbers.**

[phoxis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7346409/3920237)'s answer to [srand() — why call only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-only-once):

> Initializing once the initial state with the seed value will generate
>   enough random numbers as you do not set the internal state with srand,
>   **thus making the numbers more probable to be random.**

Perhaps they're simply using imprecise language, none of the explanations seem to explain why calling `srand` multiple times is bad (aside from producing the same sequence of random numbers) or how it affects the "randomness" of the numbers. Can somebody clear this up for me?

Comment: *Per se*: No. Provide contexts or we cannot tell to what extent the quality is affected.

Comment: @Columbo there are multiple issues with `srand` for serious usage. One of it is that the distribution is biased. See e.g. http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx for some discussion, although I remember I've seen something similar on SO, although cannot find it now.

Comment: @vsoftco Unrelated? We are talking about the *difference* in quality, not about the qualities themselves.

Comment: @Columbo I mentioned that bias towards low-order bits is a problem, and in my opinion the most serious one. This is a difference in quality, and linked a page, which was quite long to explain in my post. In other words, the entropy of the source is quite far from being `H(|X|)`, where `|X|` is the size of the alphabet.

Comment: @vsoftco We have to cases: Seed rand once, and seed rand several times. Now we are concerned about the difference in quality of the produced sequences. How does the page you linked in any way relate to this issue?

Comment: @Columbo, this is another issue, regarding `srand`'s sensibility to its initial seed. IMHO, it is way less important, as you can seed it only once, and not `1000000` per second (in the latter case you know you get the same seed, due to `time(0)` issue). The real problem in `rand` is that even if you seed it once per program, your sequence is far from being random. Maybe I didn't explain the whole issue quite well, will try to improve on my answer.

Comment: @vsoftco You are totally mixing up two functions. `srand` and `rand` are not the same, the former is associated solely with the seeding, and the latter with the PRNG itself.

Comment: @vsoftco This isn't another issue, this is *the* issue. This question is not about the quality of `rand` itself.

Comment: @Columbo the reason I mentioned `rand` quality is that it is not so well known, and you find code involving `rand` even in critical cryptographic components, which is a huge huge mistake.

Comment: @remyabel, they **NEVER** use imprecise language.  They try always to use the most precise description, just to eliminate whatever possible misinterpretation you can do.  Suppose you call (in a for loop) ten times the srand() function and try to get some random numbers in between.  You'll sure get ten times **the same sequence** of numbers (you can change the second in the middle, but that's not probable)  This is an extreme example of how randomness can be lost by not thinking twice.

Answer (score 4):

Look at the source of `srand()` from this question: [Rand Implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4768180/rand-implementation)

Also, example implementation from this thread:

```
static unsigned long int next = 1;

int rand(void) // RAND_MAX assumed to be 32767
{
    next = next * 1103515245 + 12345;
    return (unsigned int)(next/65536) % 32768;
}

void srand(unsigned int seed)
{
    next = seed;
}
```

As you can see, when you calling `srand(time(0))` you will got new numbers on `rand()` depends on seed. Numbers will repeat after some milions, but calling `srand` again will make it other. Anyway, it must repeat after some cycles - but order depends on argument for `srand`. This is why C rand isn't good for cryptography - you can predict next number when you know seed.

If you have fast loop, calling `srand` every iteration is without sense - you can got same number while your `time()` (1 second is very big time for modern CPUs) give another seed.

There is no reason in simple app to call srand multiple times - this generator are weak by design and if you want real random numbers, you must use other (the best I know is *Blum Blum Shub*)

For me, there is no more or less random numbers - it always depends on seed, and they repeat if you use same seed. Using time is good solution because it's easy to implement, but you must use only one (at beginning of `main()`) or when you sure that you calling `srand(time(0))` in another second.

Answer (score 2):

A pseudo random generator is an engine which produce numbers that look almost random. However, they are completely deterministic. In other words, given a seed `x0`, they are produced by repeated application of some injective function on `x0`, call it `f(x0)`, so that `f^m(x0)` is quite different from `f^{m-1}(x0)` or `f^{m+1}(x0)`, where the notation `f^m` denotes the function composition `m` times. In other words, `f(x)` has huge jumps, almost uncorrelated with the previous ones.

If you use `sradnd(time)` multiple times in a second, you may get the same seed, as the clock is not as fast as you may imagine. So the resulting sequence of random numbers will be the same. And this may be a (huge) problem, especially in cryptography applications (anyway, in the latter case, people **buy** good number generators based on real-time physical processes such as temperature difference in atmospheric data etc, or, recently, on measuring quantum bits, e.g. superposition of polarized photons, the latter being truly random, as long as quantum mechanics is correct.)

There are also other serious issues with `rand`. One of it is that the distribution is biased. See e.g. http://eternallyconfuzzled.com/arts/jsw_art_rand.aspx for some discussion, although I remember I've seen something similar on SO, although cannot find it now.

If you plan to use it in crypto applications, just don't do it. Use `<random>` and a serious random engine like Mersene's twister `std::mt19937` combined with `std::random_device`

If you seed your random number generator twice using `srand`, and get different seeds, then
you will get two sequences that will be quite different. This may be satisfactory for you. However, each sequence per se will not be a good random distribution due to the issues I mentioned above. On the other hand, if you seed your rng too many times, you will get the same seed, and THIS IS BAD, as you'll generate the same numbers over and over again.

PS: seen in the comments that pseudo-numbers depend on a seed, and this is bad. This is the definition of pseudo-numbers, and it is not a bad thing as it allows you to repeat numerical experiments with the same sequence. The idea is that each **different** seed should produce a sequence of (almost) random numbers, different from a previous sequence (technically, you shouldn't be able to distinguish them from a perfect random sequence).

Comment: There are no serious issues regarding `srand`. There are serious issues with `rand`, but that has nothing to do with the seeding of it.

Comment: @Columbo, sorry, yes, I meant `rand`, after the seeding, will update. Ok, updated, hope I clarified the issue a bit. In any case, thanks for questioning, as it makes me think more and give a better answer.

Comment: `std::mt19937` and `std::random_device` are not cryptographically secure. If you need random numbers for cryptography, you need to use a cryptography library, not the stuff in the standard library.

Answer (score 2):

The numbers `rand()` returns are not actually random but "pseudo-random." What this means is that `rand()` generates a stream of numbers that look random for given values of "look" and "random" from an internal state that changes with each call.

As a rule, `rand()` is what is called a linear congruental generator, which means that uses a mechanism roughly like this:

```
int state; // persistent state

int rand() {
  state = (a * state + b) % c;
  return state;
}
```

with carefully chosen constants `a`, `b` and `c`. `c` tends to be a power of two in practice because that makes it faster to calculate.

The "randomness" of this sequence depends in part on the persistence of the state. If the sequence is constantly reseeded with predictable values, the return values of `rand()` become predictable in turn. How critical this is depends on the application, but it is not a purely academical consideration. Consider, for example, the case

```
a = 69069
b = 1
c = 2^32
```

which was used, for example, by old versions of glibc. Granted that I picked this example for the obviousness of the pattern, but the point remains in less obvious cases. Imagine this RNG were seeded with a sequence of incrementing numbers n, n+1, n+2 and so forth -- you will get from `rand()` a sequence of numbers, each 69069 larger than the last (modulo 2^32). The pattern will be plainly visible. Starting with 0, we would get

```
1
69070
138139
207208
...
```

rising until a bit over 4 billion in steady increments. And to make matters worse, some implementation actually returned the seed value in the first call of `rand` after a call to `srand`, in which case you'd just get your seeds back.

Answer (score 1):

The seed determines what random numbers will be generated, in order, i.e. `srand(1)`, will always generate the same number on the first call to `rand()`, the same on the second call to `rand()` and so on.

In other words, if you re-seeded with the same seed before each `rand()` invocation, you'd generate the same random number every single time.

So successive seeding with `time(0)`, during a single second, will mean all your random numbers after re-seeding are actually the same number.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the other answers are saying exactly what the question already stated: multiple calls to `srand` with the same second will produce the same seed.  I believe the *actual* question is the same one that I had, which is: why would it be bad to call `srand` multiple times, even if it was with a different seed every time?

I can think of three reasons:

1. People are not clear in their language and they actually mean `srand` should not be called multiple times with `time()` if you want different sequences of random numbers.
2. It's cryptographically bad because every seed passed to `srand` is not itself a random number (well, it's probably not).  Meaning, every `srand` is injecting a chance for someone to guess that seed and therefore predict your stream of pseudo-random numbers.
3. It can mess up the distribution of pseudo-random numbers.  @vsoftco's answer gave me a clue.  If you call `srand` once, `rand` can be designed to give you a uniform distribution of pseudo-random numbers over its lifetime.  If you call `srand` in the middle, however, you'll throw off that uniform distribution because it would "start over" with a new seed.

So, if you don't care about any of that, I would think it's okay to call `srand` more than once.  In my case, I want to call it at the start of my program, but call it again after a `fork()` because the seed is apparently shared across child processes, and I want each child process to have its own sequence of pseudo-random numbers.

---

Going back to why it's cryptographically bad, it's easier to guess a seed if it's something like `time()` because a bad actor can try to guess the time it was seeded.  That is why calling `srand` at the start of a program might be better, because it could be less likely that someone would guess that time as well as, say, when a server request was initiated.

But I would surmise that even passing nanoseconds would be cryptographically dangerous if there's a chance the underlying clock doesn't have that kind of precision.  Imagine, for example, that you call `srand(get_time_in_ns())` and the underlying clock only returns time to the nearest millisecond.

Now, I'm no crypto expert in any way, but this leads me to wonder if it would be safer than current-time to pass the output of a *different* pseudo-random generator as seeds to multiple `srand` calls?  For example, can you call each `srand` with a number from Linux's `/dev/random`?  (I imagine you might want to do that if you want a safer seed than the current time but still want to use `rand()` so you don't have the overhead of reading from the kernel every time.)