# How do I avoid printing duplicate numbers? [C language]

Tags: c

[output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kfDgm.png)

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randint(void);

int main(void) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", randint());
    }

    return 0;
}

int randint(void) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    return rand() % 81 + 10;
}
```

My intention is to print 10 different numbers. However, 10 duplicate numbers are printed continuously each time. How can I resolve this issue?

I used library functions like the `srand()` function. And I changed the position of the function little by little, but the result was the same.

**Expected**
84 40 35 60 45 84 40 77 37 11

**Output**
11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11 11

Comment: You're calling `srand()` before each `rand()` which resets the seed. You only need to call it once.

Comment: Or, you could add a 1-2 second delay between loop iterations... :-)

Comment: [srand() — why call it only once?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7343833/srand-why-call-it-only-once)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call to the `srand()` routine ought to occur only once, in such a use case as yours at least, though in many cases that's the norm. For further reading you can refer to this question: [How does calling srand more than once affect the quality of randomness?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27209282/how-does-calling-srand-more-than-once-affect-the-quality-of-randomness)

By placing it within the routine, you're invoking it every time, thus constantly altering your seed, which in this case it but resets it, therefore producing identical values for each invocation.

To get rid of this unwanted behaviour you ought to place `srand()` within the main function, or at least at a location that's both prior to the call to `rand()`, and outside a loop, or other structure which will get invoked repeatedly, such as your function.

Here's a revised version of your code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randint(void);

int main(void) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", randint());
    }

    return 0;
}

int randint(void) {
    return rand() % 81 + 10;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your the seed only once for all, not each time you need a random number otherwise, the same succession of numbers is generated and you always pick the first one.

I think your code shoud be :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

int randint(void);

int main(void) {
    srand((unsigned)time(NULL));

    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
        printf("%d ", randint());
     }

    return 0;
}

int randint(void) {
    return rand() % 81 + 10;
}
```