# How to optimize many rand() calls?

Tags: c++, optimization, random, particle-system

I have a particle simulator that requires many calls for random numbers, mainly between 0.0-1.0. It does this for every particle generated so you can see it adds up.

I counted no fewer than 60 of them per iteration: `(double)(rand() % RAND_MAX) / (RAND_MAX)`

They are used for many features ranging from color randomness to size to velocity to forces, etc.

My question is two-fold:

1. Does the rand() function take a big toll on performance or is 60 of them, per particle, not worth worrying about? I could easily have 1000 particles so that would equate to 60,000 random calls!
2. I know I could compute say 5 random floats and re-use those throughout the 60 calls but I worry that's a bad idea and I'll start seeing inconsistencies due to the re-use. Computing just one and reusing that would probably be a terrible idea, right?

Is there any other better way to optimize this?

Comment: It’s a pseudorandom generator. That means it has a fixed duration. You should just use a profiler

Comment: "Computing just one and reusing that... " Reminds me of https://xkcd.com/221/

Comment: [`rand` is typically implemented quite efficiently with a LCG](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4768189/364696) (it's just a terrible source of randomness in terms of bias, range, etc.). For scientific purposes, it's probably fine though, and the speed should be fine as well. Feel free to profile if the code is running too slowly (and you've actually turned on optimizations in the compiler) to check, but I doubt you'll find a meaningfully faster source of pseudorandom numbers.

Comment: Hi ShadowRanger - thanks for your thoughts. So it sounds like it's not a big issue to have that many calls per loop made? I don't see any way to optimize it anyway unless I reuse which doesn't sound like a good idea.

Comment: Funny thing... `rand` is so loosely specified that the code in the XKCD link from Igor would be a valid implementation.

Comment: Recommendation: Write what you have in mind. Run it. If it's too slow, profile it to see where it's slow. If that turns out to be the calls to `rand`, THAT is when you should start looking for a faster alternative. That said, I'm with ShadowRanger. It'll be hard to find anything much faster that doesn't do something truly stupid like `return 4;`

Comment: 1) You're programming in C++ rather than C. C++ has a much better set of alternatives. In this day and age, absolutely nobody should be using `rand()`. 2) You've told us nothing about how you're using the U(0,1) values and why you think you need 60 of them, so how do you expect anybody to help "optimize" their usage? Perhaps what you're doing could be replaced with a much better alternative, but we can't tell.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "I doubt you'll find a meaningfully faster source of pseudorandom numbers." Check out the [xoshiro](https://prng.di.unimi.it) class of generators.

Comment: @ShadowRanger "_For scientific purposes, it's probably fine though_": It is not fine for scientific purposes. It will introduce correlations and bias that can easily result in some artifact being misinterpreted as behavior of the simulated system. Also the range is likely small enough that it will repeat during the simulation, effectively causing e.g. samples to repeat and statistics to be done with misleading sample size.

Comment: Whether rand() is useful or not depends a lot on what you do with the returned value. First, rand() will not evenly populate doubles between 0 and 1.  And it's not very, well, random in a statistical sense. I had to drop using rand() in a simulation of a craps game for fun because it produced results consistently slightly off.

Comment: Should be noted that the double-precision _divide_ can be significantly more expensive than a double-precision _multiply_ on some architectures. So you may at least want to define a constant of `1.0 / RAND_MAX` somewhere. Note also that you'll _never_ get a value of `1.0` unless you use a modulus of `RAND_MAX + 1`, and hope that doesn't overflow. You should do benchmarks with C++ built-in pseudorandom engines, because those are without a doubt better than `std::rand` in terms of quality. For performance, you need to measure it.

Comment: There are non-cryptographic PRNGs based on XOR and bit shifting which work really fast if all you need is random-ish data, and often that's fine for particle simulations. All you need is a good distribution and some degree of unpredictability.

Comment: You *really* should watch this: [rand() Considered Harmful](https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=LDPMpc-ENqY)

Comment: Computing five random floats and reusing them for different features will introduce correlations (possibly even identical behaviours) between ostensibly unrelated features.   That is usually a pretty undesirable property of any simulator.   That said, `rand()` is a pretty low-quality generator so you've set the bar pretty low for quality of your simulator, so who knows.   Recent C++ standards (since 2011) provide much better quality (in the sense of "randomness" and other properties) generators than `rand()`.

Comment: Functions `rand` and `srand` are kept in the C++ standard solely for backward compatibility purposes. There is absolutely no reason to use them in new applications, as they provide next to nothing in the way of statistical guarantees. They are replaced by the facilities provided by the `<random>` header file. See the [C++11 N3551 random number generation white paper](https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf) for details.

Comment: You still haven't explained what you're doing with the 60 or more U(0,1) values per particle. Are you actually tracking 60+ distinct attributes, each of which has a uniform distribution? (That seems *a priori* unlikely, very few things in nature are uniformly distributed.) Are you summing large quantities of them to try to approximate normal distributions via the central limit theorem? Generating order statistics? Something completely different? If we knew what you were doing there might be opportunities for significant reduction in the quantity needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an answer to your question as much as a comment: Even experienced programmers cannot tell where the bottlenecks of their code are unless they actually profile the code. The same applies to your question: You are wondering whether a part of the code is a performance problem, but you present no evidence that you have measured this part, and consequently you may very well be wasting your time wondering about this issue.

So the recommendation would be: If your code is too slow, run it with a profiler and see whether the calls to generate random numbers show up anywhere close to the top. If they do, then you can start wondering about solutions. If they don't, well, then you just gained a couple of days to do something else!

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in some excellent comments and answers, in efficiency matters intuition and (even educated) guesses tend to be poor guides.

But if you happen to know the total number of random numbers generated, you can write a small test program that just generates that same count of random numbers, plus perhaps some cheap statistical moments for sanity checks purposes.

Next, you can compare the time taken by this small program with the total time taken by your actual physics application.

In order to have good and portable statistical guarantees, you can do that using the modern facilities as provided by the standard C++ `<random>` header file, rather than using the *legacy* `rand()/srand()` functions.

The C++ code of your small test program could be like this:

```
//-- https://isocpp.org/files/papers/n3551.pdf
//-- https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/numeric/random/uniform_real_distribution

#include  <iostream>
#include  <random>

int main()
{
    std::random_device  rd;  // Will be used to obtain a seed
                             // on Linux, could be:  rd{"/dev/urandom"};
    std::mt19937        gen(rd()); // Standard mersenne_twister_engine seeded with rd()
    std::uniform_real_distribution<double>  dis(0.0, 1.0);

    int     count = 60*1000*1000;
    double  sum1  = 0.0;
    double  sum2  = 0.0;
    double  r     = 0.0;

    for (int n = 0; n < count; ++n) {
        // Use dis to transform the random unsigned int generated by gen into a 
        // double in [0, 1). Each call to dis(gen) generates a new random double.
        r = dis(gen);
        sum1 += r;
        sum2 += r*r;
    }

    double avg   = sum1 / (double)count;
    double stdev = std::sqrt ((sum2 / (double)count) - avg*avg);

    std::cout << "count = " << count << '\n';
    std::cout << "average = " << avg << '\n';
    std::cout << "standard deviation = " << stdev << '\n';

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

It turns out that on a vintage Intel x86-64 PC, the time to generate 60 millions random numbers between 0.0 and 1.0 with this code is slightly below one second, using option `-O2` with compiler:

```
g++ (GCC) 12.3.1 20230508 (Red Hat 12.3.1-1)
```

So we can expect that the time taken to generate 60,000 random numbers on a modern CPU is below one millisecond.

Comment: And remember: Fast but wrong is, at best, no better than too slow.

Answer (score 2):

There's a major consideration here that nobody seems to have mentioned (and the question itself doesn't say enough to be sure whether it's an issue or not).

The potential issue arises if you call `rand()` from multiple threads of execution. `rand()` uses a (one, singular) seed value. Each time you call it, the seed value is updated so the next call can/will produce a new/different value.

To make that work from multiple threads of execution, `rand()` will typically need to protect that seed with a mutex (or something similar). If you call `rand()` from multiple threads, the code ends up being serialized, so only one call to `rand()` runs at a time.

So, even with many threads, and enough cores to run the concurrently,heavy use of `rand()` will frequently result in making effective use of only one or two cores, rather than all that are available (though the exact core usage will vary depending on how often you're using `rand()`).

The random number generators from the C++ `<random>` header don't suffer from this shortcoming. Each random number generator (that uses a seed) stores the seed in the random number generator object itself. So you can have 16 threads using 16 separate random number generator objects, with no synchronization between them at all. Note, however, that `std::random_device` will normally retrieve numbers (at least indirectly) from some random number generation hardware, so use of it frequently is more or less serialized, so you typically want to use it only to retrieve an initial seed for some pseud-random generator. The library also directly supports generating numbers in a range, so (unlike your current code) the numbers you generate in the 0.0 ... 1.0 range won't be biased.